# in R How to compare NA and NA, and return TRUE or FALSE?

Tags: r, na, logical-operators

I would like to have a way to compare `NA` and `NA` and return TRUE or FALSE.

---

For example,

```
a = c(1,2,3,NA)
b = c(1,2,NA,NA)
```

And suppose we would like to compare `a` and `b`. The R default output is

```
a>=b
# TRUE TRUE   NA   NA
a>b
# FALSE FALSE    NA    NA
a==b
# TRUE TRUE   NA   NA
```

Is there a simple function or method to have a return like the following result?

```
a>=b
# TRUE TRUE   NA   TRUE
a>b
# FALSE FALSE    NA    FALSE
a==b
# TRUE TRUE   NA   TRUE
```

This should be logical because `NA` (in `a`) is the same as `NA` (in `b`).

Comment: `a == b | (is.na(a) & is.na(b))`

Comment: In general, it's not a great idea to return TRUE when comparing missing values. Consider testing the equality of the diameter of the largest exoplanet in the Andromeda galaxy to Moses' waist circumference. We don't know the value of either, but we shouldn't assume they are equal because they are both NA.